# How to pass variable value for table.rows.cells to get table cell value?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am facing a difficulty in passing variable for a cell value to get the content in the table cell.
Passing the row variable will detect but not the col variable.

```
var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
//displaying row and col variables do work.
//This is the result I am getting <button style="display:block; width: 100%;">Actual Cell Value</button>
var cellValue;
cellValue = document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[row].cells[col].innerHTML;
alert(cellValue);

//This one returns correct cell value
alert(document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[row].cells[0].innerHTML);
```

Comment: add more code man.

Comment: passing variable in cells[variable] is what not working, but cells[0] does work.

Comment: you have not initialized row, col values

Comment: I did sir, I am getting from other code

Comment: @GemeAlex - Paste your HTML as well, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accessing DOM properly, also note that index method returns index position from 0.

Your code works fine if i pass below.

```
var col = 2;
var row = 3;

var cellValue;
cellValue = document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[row].cells[col].innerHTML;
console.log(cellValue);

console.log(document.getElementById("dataTable").rows[row].cells[0].innerHTML);
```